# Tkinter text wont fit on page

Tags: tkinter, text, textbox, format

[image: the text wont conform to a regular paragraph and cuts off]Im trying to add a massive paragraph of text about 20 lines to my Tkiner window. However I cant format it in a way that i can see it all. Iv tried splitting it into seperate paragraphs but each paragraph has a cut of point after like a few words. Can you please help on the format of the Label?

The widget is a label, and attached is picture of what it looks like.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. We need to know what type of widget you're using (message, label, text, canvas, ...), how you're adding it to the screen (pack, place, grid), and how you're setting the text.

Comment: when I call a function that prints a line of text within a tkinter label, it prints it in the IDE console rather than the window. Help will be appreciated

Comment: Like I said in an earlier comment, please show us what your code looks like. There are plenty of tutorials out there which show how to display long lines of text on the screen. It's not at all clear what your asking or why you need our help.

Answer (score 0):

what you've asked is not very clear but ill just say some stuff and hope it will work.

1)You can use the \n Function to create a new line
2)when you pack the frame that the label is in use: fill=BOTH function after setting what side to pack too.

Sorry if this is no help.

Next time please attach some code so we can get a more detailed problem and look as to what's going on.